# VLC Mac play videos in filename order?

Tags: vlc-media-player

Is there any way to sort & play in FILE NAME order

There is a TITLE column to sort by, but that is the title embedded inside the file. Not the file name.

MAC
Version 3.0.16 Vetinari (Intel 64bit)

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367737/batch-remove-mkv-titles-only-no-re-encode for how to strip [or change] the internal title names

Comment: As a workaround, you could sort by URI - but only if they're all in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to provide an answer rather than comments…

VLC does not consider the actual file name in its sort methods. The only name sort you can do is by *Title*
This title is embedded in the file [by methods above my paygrade].
Mac VLC does not "truncate the title" as claimed in another answer… so long as the internal title matches the file name. If it doesn't, then as soon as you click inside the playlist after drag & drop, the names will change to the internal title field.
Unless the media files are specifically 'de-named' the actual file name has no bearing.

If the file name & title are the same, then of course, sorting by filename is possible.

The only way I know to change this is to change the internal Title.
See this QA on our sister site [Ask Different - Batch-remove mkv titles only, no re-encode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367737/batch-remove-mkv-titles-only-no-re-encode) for a working method to do this on mkv files. You can either change the title to the file name or rename specifically. I don't know how to achieve this on other file types.

Answer (score 0):

Testing this on MacOS (Big Sur 11.5.2) Version of VLC Player Version 3.0.16 Vetinari (Intel 64bit) to try and replicate the issue using a series of videos saved as (E01 title.mp4, E02 title.mp4, E03 title.mp4, E04 title.mp4) and when playing, MacOS will truncate the title of the episodes from "E01" to "E1" removing the "0" from the video title, but still plays in order.

Looking at the VLC wiki documentation under Playlist (https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Playlist/) shows that sorting in MacOS is done by "clicking the header of the column matching the criteria you want to use for sorting." So, that may exhaust the sorting option via VLC, but I wanted to see if there were other ways to address this.

Keeping that in mind, I tried a few different ways to sort the files in the playlist without luck. The only other viable options would be to manually sort the playlist by dragging and dropping (https://osxdaily.com/2017/12/05/play-multiple-videos-mac-video-playlist/) or by batch renaming the files to get them in the desired order by using replace text (https://appleinsider.com/articles/21/06/23/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-macos), highlighting the troublesome files and batch renaming them through finder (https://www.alphr.com/batch-rename-files-mac/).

Comment: They are already named in the order I want so renaming them will do nothing

The TITLE column looks like it uses the name embedded (title property) in the file when it was created

Comment: Mac VLC does not "truncate the title"… so long as the *internal* title matches the file name. If it doesn't, then as soon as you click inside the playlist after drag & drop, the names will change to the internal title field. Unless the media files are specifically 'de-named' the file name has no bearing.